# rollup build scss error.tip: Error: Unexpected character '@' (Note that you need plugins to import files that are not JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, rollup

[image]

This is my code. I want build Vuejs components. But tip error message when building.

SCSS and PostCSS plugin are unless.

```js
import nodeResolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve'
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs'
import { babel } from '@rollup/plugin-babel'
import { terser } from 'rollup-plugin-terser'
import { eslint } from 'rollup-plugin-eslint'
import image from '@rollup/plugin-image'
import alias from '@rollup/plugin-alias'
import vuePlugin from 'rollup-plugin-vue'

const isDev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'

export default [
    {
        input: 'src/index.js',
        external: ['ms'],
        output: [
            {
                name: 'cjs',
                file: 'lib/index.js',
                format: 'cjs',
                plugins: [
                    babel({
                        exclude: 'node_modules/**', 
                        babelHelpers: 'runtime'
                        // runtimeHelpers: true 
                    })
                ]
            },
            {
                name: 'cjs',
                file: 'lib/index.min.js',
                format: 'cjs',
                plugins: [
                    terser(),
                    babel({
                        exclude: 'node_modules/**',
                        extensions: [
                            '.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx', '.vue'
                        ],
                        babelHelpers: 'runtime'
                        // runtimeHelpers: true 
                    })
                ]
            },
            {
                name: 'es',
                file: 'es/index.js',
                format: 'es'
            },
            {
                name: 'umd',
                file: 'dist/index.js',
                format: 'umd',
                plugins: [isDev && terser()]
            }
        ],
        plugins: [
            eslint({
                // fix: true,
                // throwOnError: true,
                // throwOnWarning: true,
                include: ['src/**'],
                exclude: ['node_modules/**']
            }),
            alias({
                entries: [
                    {
                        find: '@assets',
                        replacement: './src/assets'
                    }
                ]
            }),
            // scss({
            //     output: 'dist/main.css'
            // }),
            vuePlugin({
                // css: false
                // preprocessStyles: false
                // preprocessOptions: {
                //     scss: {
                //         additionalData: `@import 'src/assets/styles/varibles.scss'`,
                //         data: `@import 'src/assets/styles/mixins.scss'`
                //     }
                // }
            }),

            // postcss({
            //     use: {
            //         sass: {
            //             data: [
            //                 `@import 'src/assets/styles/varibles.scss'`,
            //                 `@import 'src/assets/styles/mixins.scss'`
            //             ]
            //         }
            //     }
            // }),
            image(),
            nodeResolve()
            commonjs(),
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: `plugin are unless`, meant `useless` I guess?

Comment: How did you created your app? Tried the Vue CLI?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi guys,I'm make a demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-northcutt-gbqnr4?file=/rollup.config.js